# Function to move scroll to the right-top corner of DIV in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<div style=width:200px;height:200px;border-style:solid;overflow:scroll;>
  <div style=width:500px;height:500px;>
    Text, something
  </div>
</div>
```

This is example html code. I need to move view (Scroll) of div to right-top on event (For example on button click).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try jQuery [.scrollLeft()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/). Here is the working code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#scroll').click(function() {
    var $scroll = $('.scrollthis');
    $scroll.parent().scrollLeft($scroll.width());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:200px; height:150px; border-style:solid; overflow:scroll;">
  <div class="scrollthis" style="width:500px; height:500px;">
    Text, something
  </div>
</div>
<button id="scroll">Scroll</button>
```

Comment: this one does not scroll to the right top. it just scrolls to the right edge. try scrolling to bottom left corner and hit the Scroll button.

Answer (score 2):

`scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` is the correct way but you can add animation and dynamic values for a better flexibility: https://jsfiddle.net/twey5d7u/

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
$(MainDiv).scrollLeft(DivInsideWidth);
$(MainDiv).scrollTop(0);
```